# iText pdf functionality broken after lib upgrade - cannot merge tables

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itextpdf

Ugrading the [iText PDF library](http://itextpdf.com/) from 2.0.4 to 5.4.1 has broken the existing functionality in my application.

Merging tables into one complex table does not work anymore.

```
//Creating tables
Table table0 = new Table(2);
Table table1 = new Table(7);
Table table2 = new Table(17);
Table table3 = new Table(24);

//Setting widths for tables
table0.setWidths(widths0);
table3.setWidths(widths);
table1.setWidths(widths1);

//Inserting 3 tables into one
Cell cell;
cell = new Cell(table1);
table0.addCell(cell);
Cell cell2 = new Cell(table2);
table0.addCell(cell2);
Cell cell3 = new Cell(table3);
cell3.setColspan(2);
table0.addCell(cell3);

//Populating cells and data for table1, table2, table3...

//Adding table to my pdf document
document.add(table0);
document.close();
```

Actual result: `table0` which is being added to the document is not showing up at all. (I tried adding tables 1,2,3 separately and they showed up)
The same code was working with older version of iText PDF.

BG Info: Also java version has upgraded from 1.5 -> 1.7, jBoss from 4.0.4 -> 6.1, but i consider it is probably not related to my trouble.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080932/pdfptable-vs-table-vs-simpletable

Comment: thanks, some good info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Table` class was removed from iText. It was replaced by `PdfPTable`. You'll have to change your code. Many years have passed between iText 2.0.4 and 5.4.1.

Comment: Hey. Yes you are right, I already figured it out and it seems for me that there is too much to do, to get the code in accordance with 5.4.1. So i rolled back to 2.0.4 and restored old "com.lowagie" lib imports in existing classes. For any new developments, most probably will try to use 5.4.1 :)

Comment: Or 5.4.3 (released yesterday)

Comment: Maybe its worth doing a minor upgrade to 2.1.7 which is 2 years newer. And it is easy to upgrade since there shouldn't be any change necessary...