# iText column width wrong

Tags: java, android, itext

Im using iText in android to build a pdf file with a table . It seems easy to do but the result is wrong. Help appreciated!

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(output));
    Document documento = new Document(pdfDoc);

    float[] columnWidths = new float[]{40, 160, 50, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25};
    Table table = new Table(columnWidths);
    table.setWidth(500);


    com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell cell = new com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell(1, columnWidths.length).add("(Continuação)");
    table.addHeaderCell(cell);

    cell = new com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell(1, columnWidths.length).add("Continua...");
    table.addFooterCell(cell);

    table.setSkipFirstHeader(true);
    table.setSkipLastFooter(true);

    Cell cellA;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        cellA = new Cell(1, 1).add(String.valueOf(i+1));
        cellA.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        cellA.setWidth(40);
        cellA.setFontSize(7);
        table.addCell(cellA);

        cellA = new Cell(1, 1).add("ALYNE BORGES MADEIRA");
        cellA.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
        cellA.setWidth(160);
        cellA.setFontSize(7);
        table.addCell(cellA);

        cellA = new Cell(1, 1).add("100.00");
        cellA.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        cellA.setWidth(50);
        cellA.setFontSize(7);
        table.addCell(cellA);

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cellA = new Cell(1, 1).add("10.00");
            cellA.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            cellA.setWidth(25);
            cellA.setFontSize(7);
            table.addCell(cellA);
        }

    }
```

The problem is in the last column where width is not equal to prior 9.

[image]

Comment: why do you have the column widths different from the cell widths?

Comment: Let me correct that. Is effect from all changes and tests.

Comment: Have you measured the actual cell sizes? Are they the actual number of pixels you laid out in the array? If the middle cells are not actually 25 pixels wide, there may be some scaling being done, and the last column is being padded out to fill the page.

Comment: @Bob Dalgleish: It could be, but at this point I'm beginning to believe that is an iText's problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Summary***

If you are only using it to generate PDF tables instead of needing RTF and HTML output, then it might be better to use the PdfPTable class [Table is now unsupported] which is better supported and less prone to quirks (as explained here: [PdfpTable vs. Table (vs. SimpleTable?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080932/pdfptable-vs-table-vs-simpletable)).

***Sizing***

If you use PdfPTable with `setWidths(float[])` then you should be able to do absolute widths without needing to specify the width in each cell for code readability. (You can also use percentage widths, which, for a basic table, might be easier to get aligned properly on the page.)

***Headers & Footers***

Since you are using headers & footers, PdfPTable has `setHeaderRows(int)` and `setFooterRows(int)`, but note that:

> The number of footer rows are subtracted from the header rows. For example, for a table with two header rows and one footer row the code would be:
>
> `table.setHeaderRows(3);`
>
> `table.setFooterRows(1);`

***PdfPCell Porting***

Also note that PdfPCell has changed `setTextAlignment` to be setHorizontalAlignment.

***Examples and Documentation***

Some examples of using it are here (note the usage of `setLockedWidth`: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/cell-and-table-widths

The JavaDoc for PdfPTable is here: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html

And the JavaDoc for PdfPCell is here: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell.html

Comment: Thank you, Halcyon, for your help. All makes sense. I will check in detail.