# PDFcells not displaying correctly, few cells are moving to next page in PdfWriter in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, export, pdf-writer

I am trying to create the PDF using the PdfWriter.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("some file path"));
document.open();

Font font1 = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD);
font1.setSize(10);
font1.setColor(Color.BLUE);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
table.setWidths(new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 });
table.setSpacingBefore(10);
table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
//cell1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell1.setBackgroundColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
cell1.setPadding(5);
font1.setColor(Color.WHITE);    
cell1.setPhrase();

table.addCell(cell1);
```

My PDF looks like this :
[image]

Why the cells are all distorted is what i dont understand

Comment: Do you want all your cells to be of the same size regardless of the content?

Comment: Yes I want to see the cell in same page,it shouldnt break when cell text is too large and move to next page , I tried with .setKeepTogether(true); but that also didnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iText column width wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429013/itext-column-width-wrong)

Comment: No, it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: The code you shared adds only one cell to the table and doesn't add the table to the document at all. Please share enough code to allow reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
tablename.setSplitLate(false);
```

is the one fixed the issue.

```
    /**
     * If true the row will only split if it's the first one in an empty page.
     * It's true by default.
     * It's only meaningful if setSplitRows(true).
     * 
     * @param splitLate the property value
     */
    public void setSplitLate(boolean splitLate) {
        this.splitLate = splitLate;
    }
```